# How to Ignore Daylight Savings

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

I am receiving some data from web service and one of the fields is the Data object.

For instance, `2014-06-30T07:45:00+02:00` is the DateTime value.

When I try to parse this and get the time via

```
var time = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-30T07:45:00+02:00").TimeOfDay;
```

I get `8:45:00` instead of `7:45:00`

Is it possible to ignore the daylight savings ? since web service returning the correct Date anyway ?

Comment: Be explicit what you want, use the Parse() overload that allows you to pass DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal so you get UTC back.

Comment: @HansPassant when I use AdjustToUniversal, I get 5:45:00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

`var time = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-06-30T07:45:00+02:00").DateTime.TimeOfDay;`

Comment: Var keyword is exactly the opposite of what you said.

Comment: Eh, actually you'd use var if the return type is so obvious you'd feel silly for copying it, the only time you'd _not_ use var is for documentation purposes.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. While `var` can be used when you feel lazy/silly, I think it makes your code less readable. Also @DmitryDovgopoly, I do not see how it's the opposite of what I said. If you know what you're going to get in return, then I think you should specify it. Otherwise you have no choice but to use `var` e.g. with anonymous types.

Comment: It still returns 8:45:00

Comment: See my update. I've removed the comment about the `var` keyword as I believe it's a matter of personal choice mostly.